# How to substract two dataframe when index does not exactly match the index of the other data frame

Tags: python

I have the following Dataframes

### DF1

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 5 |
| Index2 | 5 |
| Index3 | 5 |
| Index4 | 5 |
| Index5 | 5 |
| Index6 | 5 |
| Index7 | 5 |

### DF2

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 2 |
| Index2 | 2 |
| Index3 | 2 |
| Index4 | 2 |

When I do :

```
DF1['Val'].subtract(DF2['Val'])
```

I have the following output :

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 3 |
| Index2 | 3 |
| Index3 | 3 |
| Index4 | 3 |
| Index5 | NaN |
| Index6 | NaN |
| Index7 | NaN |

And the excepted output would be :

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 3 |
| Index2 | 3 |
| Index3 | 3 |
| Index4 | 3 |
| Index5 | 5 |
| Index6 | 5 |
| Index7 | 5 |

What am I missing ?

---

What to do when the index of `DF2` is longer than `DF1`:
We should have negative values, how to display them?

DF1

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 5 |
| Index2 | 5 |
| Index3 | 5 |
| Index4 | 5 |
| Index5 | 5 |
| Index6 | 5 |
| Index7 | 5 |

DF2

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 5 |
| Index2 | 5 |
| Index3 | 5 |
| Index4 | 5 |
| Index5 | 5 |
| Index6 | 5 |
| Index7 | 5 |
| Index8 | 5 |

### The output would be

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index1 | 0 |
| Index2 | 0 |
| Index3 | 0 |
| Index4 | 0 |
| Index5 | 0 |
| Index6 | 0 |
| Index7 | 0 |
| Index8 | -5 |

---

### More Complex One : DF1

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index4 | 5 |
| Index5 | 5 |

### DF2

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index5 | 5 |
| Index6 | 5 |
| Index7 | 5 |

### Output

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| Index4 | 5 |
| Index5 | 0 |
| Index6 | -5 |
| Index7 | -5 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({'Val':[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'Val':[2, 2, 2, 2]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

DF3 = pd.DataFrame({'Val':[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

You can do:

```
DF1['Val'].subtract(DF2['Val'].reindex(DF1.index, fill_value=0))
```

```
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    5
5    5
6    5
Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

For your second question, it's the opposite:

```
DF1['Val'].reindex(DF2.index, fill_value=0).subtract(DF2['Val'])
```

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7   -5
Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:**
For the more complex case (where there is an index overlap but one is not a subset of the other):

```
DF4 = pd.DataFrame({'Val':[5, 5]}, index=[4, 5])

DF5 = pd.DataFrame({'Val':[5, 5, 5]}, index=[5, 6, 7])

common_index = DF4.index.union(DF5.index)
DF4['Val'].reindex(common_index, fill_value=0).subtract(DF5['Val'].reindex(common_index, fill_value=0))
```

```
4    5
5    0
6   -5
7   -5
Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Is it possible to define the index so we don't miss Index from DF1 and DF2 ? 
DF1 Index = a,b
DF2 Index = b,c

The Index Excepted would be a,b,c

Comment: Please see the edit, your answer will work 80% of the time

Comment: @TourEiffel edited with the solution

Comment: Thank you v Much for this really complete and detailed answer !